# How to send integers (used scale from Tkinter) from Python 3 to Arduino and get the correct integer returned back

Tags: python, arduino

My Python 3 code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import serial
import struct

ser = serial.Serial('COM4',9600)# establish a connection with  port

root = Tk()

root.geometry('500x500+50+50')
root.title('ARDIUNO LED SLIDER')

##################################

def print_value(val):
#struct.pack('>B', 45)# tried this but not working
    ser.write(str(val).encode())
    print(ser.readline())


###############################

#Note that to pass the from option as a keyword argument,
# you need to add a trailing underscore (from is a reserved keyword in    Python).
w = Scale(root, from_=0, to=100,length=400,   orient=HORIZONTAL,command=print_value)
w.pack(side=TOP,anchor=S)

root.mainloop()
```

My Arduino code:
This an Arduino code done on Uno

```cpp
void setup() {
   // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);// declare pin 9 to be an o/p

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {  //  looking for availability of data in     serial monitor

    data= Serial.read();// read the data from serial monitor
    //Serial.println(int(data));
    Serial.write(data);


  delay(100);
  }
}
```

The error I get is:

1. Some times it hangs
2. Other times I get the following error message when I move the slider

   ```
   raise TypeError('unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: {!r}'.format(seq))
   TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: '10'
   ```

Comment: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9627/send-multiple-int-values-from-python-to-arduino-using-pyserial //even this method i tried its not helping in my case

Comment: when i use timeout=1 arg while creating serial in python am getting output like this ////---> b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'     but i want the same number returned what to do

Comment: Suggest you write val out to the console from python and see exactly what it's trying to send to the serial.  Also, doing the serial communications in-line is asking for trouble, not certain howscale works.. but I think every time you move the slider 1 pixel, python has to go through the very slow process of sending and receiving serial data.  This will probably be why it hangs. You should set a variable (e.g push the value onto a stack) when the slider moves, and in parallel send that variable to the serial connection.

Comment: @jeffUK  what about the hexa o/p i got in in prev command while setting timeout of 1???

Comment: If you print(val).. you'll see what is being sent to the arduino too; if you're sending x00 then it's working correctly and the problem is with the python... either way it will help identify where the problem is.

Comment: @jeffUK i print(val) and checked it shows 2 or 4 depending on the number i send.i think it shows the bytes it sending

Comment: v=struct.pack('>i',22) ,here instead of 'i' what should i put to send a group of integer values?